# Android Studio // Import statement error // Unused import statement

Tags: java, android, import, syntax-error

Everytime I want to `import` anything the `import` statement line just disappears and gives me the following error:

```
Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.
     Details: Current thread: Thread[JobScheduler FJ pool 7/8,6,main] 1239762171
     Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.5.1#AI-134.1061098, eap:true,6,main] 198746559
     SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.5.1#AI-134.1061098, eap:true,6,main] 198746559
```

Any solution for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66854; the workaround is to disable the "Optimize imports on the fly" preference until we get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Disabling "Optimize imports on the fly" removes the error, but the imports are grey and it says: "Unused import statement". Any solution for that?

Comment: It colors an import gray when it's unused. It's not harmful for there to be an unused import statement, so it's a warning, not an error. If you're not using it, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have "Optimize imports on the fly" enabled, which automatically removes unused imports. You likely also have "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" selected, which automatically adds imports you need. The solution is to write the code first, and watch your imports be added automatically, and manually add any ambiguous ones, as they become needed. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html?search=optim

In the event this does not work for you, or if you simply prefer to enter your own import statements, then simply disable the features in settings > Editor > Auto Import.