# Android studio 0.86 cannot resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, resolve

I'm using android studio for some time and today, suddenly, I encountered a weird problem. All the imports on the first rows of every activity says: "Unused import statement" and on every object or method in the application I see the error message: "Cannot resolve method" or "Cannot resolve symbol". I've tried to clean and rebuild the project, I downloaded the SDK again. What else can I do except delete the project and start again?

Answer (score 0):

Try syncing the gradle and look for possible errors in the log.

Comment: I tried Sync Project With Gradle Files and the log only shows me "Gradle build finished in 2 sec"

Answer (score 0):

This question:

[Android Studio // Import statement error // Unused import statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267839/android-studio-import-statement-error-unused-import-statement)

Leads to this known issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66854

Apparently disabling "Optimize Import" will fix the issue.

Comment: I checked and my "Optimize imports on the fly" is not checked. So what else could it be?